# HTML5 Form Search Input with Clean URL Query?

Tags: php, html, laravel, octobercms

I have a search input form.

```
<form action="/search">
    <input type="search" name="tags">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

It generates a URL like this

```
localhost:8888/search?tags=galaxy
```

How can I make it generate clean urls

```
localhost:8888/search/galaxy/
```

And for multiple keywords with separaters

```
localhost:8888/search?tags=galaxy+stars+space

localhost:8888/search?tags=galaxy%2C+stars%2C+space
```

This way I won't need to parse the query, since my CMS already uses clean urls it will redirect to the correct results. It doesn't have to be type="search", any input that can redirect to a clean url based on user input.

Comment: are you use any framework ??

Comment: @EhsanIlahi Laravel with OctoberCMS.

Comment: You would probably need to do something like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39849708/1144627 unless I am misunderstanding your question. Since the form action is static once the page is rendered and can't really be changed without using client side programming. As the form action determines the URL the client navigates to.

Comment: @EhsanIlahi I'd like to do it without javascript or jQuery if possible. I just need an input that redirects to /search/{users input} when pressing the submit button. I needed it clean urls because the pagination wouldn't work with my CMS using a traditional query string.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here

1- You POST the data to the server, no URL is diplayed, then the server returns a clean URL.

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $tags = $request->tags;
    return redirect()->to('search/' . $tags); //I assumed only one tag was passed
}
```

From this, you can display clean URL to the user. And add extra logique for when there are multiple tags.

2- Using Javascript `onclick` on submit to rewrite the URL

```
<input type="search" name="tags">
<input type="submit" onclick="window.location.href=this.form.action + this.form.q.value;" />
<!--/search/tags-->
```